# Using variables for mongodb field values. Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord

I'm trying to learn bot creation for Discord, and I'm trying to set up a command to take the information from the command and use it to create a doc in a MongoDB database. I've been able to do so with this code using plain string text as the values, however when I try to take variables, I'm left with an error that crashes it all together. I'm currently testing with a localhost installation of MongoDB. I'm using the latest Node.JS and MongoDB npm packages. The command is set up to take 'command user reason' for the variables.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");  
const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {  
  var dburl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";  
  var rUser = message.mentions.members.first();  
  if(!rUser) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find user.");  
  var rReason = args.join(" ").slice(22);  
  console.log("Basic variables set");  

  mongodb.connect(dburl, function(err, db) {  
    useNewUrlParser: true;  
    if (err) throw err;  
    console.log("Start connection");  
    var dbo = db.db("Viper");  
    console.log("dbo set");  
    var myobj = { time: message.createdAt, reporteduser: rUser, reportedby: 
message.author.id, reportedin: message.channel, reason: rReason };  
    console.log("myobj set");  
    dbo.createCollection("reports", function(err, res) {  
      if (err) throw err;  
      console.log("Collection created!");  
    });  
    dbo.collection("reports").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {  
      if (err) throw err;  
      console.log("1 report filed");  
    })  
    console.log("Database Created!");  
    db.close();  
    console.log("Database Closed");  
  });  
}
```

When the command is ran, I get all the console logs through "Database Closed", but then is throws an error as linked.
https://i.gyazo.com/thumb/1200/9ae8f31997a953bb1e7a25d47e964edb-png.jpg

I'm fairly new to coding so I have not the slightest clue why it's throwing this error and I haven't been able to find anything from anyone doing something similar.

EDIT:
I switched to Mongoose and was able to make it work that way.